# hot reloading vanilla js webpack simplest example

Tags: javascript, webpack, reload

Hi I am new to webpack and trying to get hot reloading working, I am not using React or Angular or anything else just vanilla JS, I've tried building the simplest example I could:

*main.js*

```
var {add_something} = require('./add_something');
var {state} = require('./state');

setInterval(()=>{
    state = add_something(state);
    console.log(state);
}, 1000);
```

*add_something.js*

```
module.exports.add_something = function(input) {
    return input + 10;
};
```

*state.js*

```
module.exports.state = 1;
```

Now when changing the add_something function to add something else then 10 and save, the page reloads alright, but it reloads completely, meaning it starts from 1 again, I'd like to keep the state intact but just add more onto it after the hot code reload.

so on the console I initially see:

```
1
11
21
31
```

then I change the add_something to add 100 instead the console shows:

```
1
101
201
301
```

where I would expect it to say:

```
131
231
331
```

oh before I forget this is my webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app:'./src/main.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: path.join(__dirname, 'es6'),
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              query: {
                  presets: ['es2015']
              }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

and I start webpack via :

```
webpack-dev-server  --hot --inline
```

on the terminal I see

```
   [77] ./src/main.js 949 bytes {0} [built]
   [78] ./src/add_something.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
   [79] ./src/state.js 26 bytes {0} [built]
```

coming by, which makes me think various chunks are being built, but I don't understand how to make this simple example work with actual hot reloading.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but you may want to start here: https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/hjs-webpack/issues/252#issuecomment-238293071